# mysql + php select from database time format

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

For some reason when I use the following query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * from exceptions where date >= DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR),'%e-%M-%Y %k:%i') and IP = '$IP' ");
```

it doesn't get the results from the past 24 hours. It does however get everything from that IP.

For the record the following query:

```
mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO exceptions (IP, Date) VALUES ('$IP', DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%e-%M-%Y %k:%i'))");
```

inserts when someone DID post something at a certain date and time.

Comment: Is `date` a `DATETIME` column? If yes, you can just do `WHERE date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR`. If no, consider making it one.

Comment: If you want to compare dates you should either use a valid mysql date field or some sort of a timestamp. Not a formatted string. What is the exact format of your column?

Comment: I think I fixed it by removing the - between de date formats. thanks for the help tho!